# Dynamic column selection based on column header in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code to select a column based on header.

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range(Range("A1:Z1").Find("Name"), Range("A1:Z1").Find("Name").End(xlDown))
```

When trying to use this range and set the XValue's on a chart

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(5).XValues = rng1
```

I see the header too comes in the list.

Wanted to know a way to select a column based on header and then remove the header element from it.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
Set rng1 = Range( _
                 Range("A1:Z1").Find("Name").Offset(1), _
                Range("A1:Z1").Find("Name").Offset(1).End(xlDown))
```

However a word of caution. `xlDown` can give you unexpected results if there is no data from the 2nd Row onwards. Also the approach that you are taking will give you an error if the name is not found.

Having said that, here is an alternative

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim aCell As Range, rng1 As Range

    '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Find the cell which has the name
        Set aCell = .Range("A1:Z1").Find("Name")

        '~~> If the cell is found
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            '~~> Get the last row in that column and check if the last row is > 1
            lRow = .Range(Split(.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            If lRow > 1 Then
                '~~> Set your Range
                Set rng1 = .Range(aCell.Offset(1), .Cells(lRow, aCell.Column))

                '~~> This will give you the address
                Debug.Print rng1.Address
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Just a revision to Siddharth's Answer (which was excellent). This code will iterate through all the rows in the specified sheet until it finds the row with the specified column header:

```
Sub Sample()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim aCell As Range, rng1 As Range
Dim i As Integer

'~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
i = 1

'Iterate through the rows until the target name is found
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        With ws
            '~~> Find the cell which has the name - build range with current iterator
            Set aCell = .Range("A" & i & ":Z" & i).Find("Name")

            '~~> If the cell is found
            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                'Set iterator equal to rows to satisfy For...Next
                i = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                 '~~> Get the last row in that column and check if the last row is > 1
                lRow = .Range(Split(.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                If lRow > 1 Then
                    '~~> Set your Range
                    Set rng1 = .Range(aCell.Offset(1), .Cells(lRow, aCell.Column))

                    '~~> This will give you the address
                    Debug.Print rng1.Address
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Just wanted to slightly improve on the previous answer! This works quite well.

Comment: Alternatively, the `Set aCell` line can read as follows for a more dynamic pull from the current sheet: `Set aCell = .Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count)).Find(What:=Name, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)`