# VBA if else and columns headers

Tags: vba

Hello I'm a newbie with VBA and macros. I've found many interesting hints about if else but I couldn't use them for my purpose. I have a sheet with many columns and alphanumeric data, I need to fill an empty column under a few conditions. I try to give an example with the following table:

```
 Tuesday Friday  Colors
 A       10      
 A       20      
 A       10      
 B       30      
 B       20      
 B       20
```

I need to fill the column colors using data from columns Tuesday and Friday, the conditions are very simple, eg:

```
If Tuesday=A and Friday=10 then Colors=Yellow.
If Tuesday=A and Friday=20 then Colors=Red
```

My problem is that I need to do it every week and the columns location can change, an example someone can add a column called Monday. The conditions do not change and are always based on columns Tuesday and Friday, moreover the column that should be filled is always named Colors. The final result should be

```
 Tuesday Friday  Colors
 A       10      Yellow
 A       20      Red
 A       10      Yellow
 B       30      Green
 B       20      Black
 B       20      Black
```

Can you please give me some advice? I'm not skilled with VBA so any related comment would be very useful for me.

Ps: the example is oversimplified but it's exactly what I need to do.

Comment: Just create a function or a sub that returns the color based on two parameters...create an onload macro that get the range of cells and call the function to write the right color in every cell

Comment: Hello Patrick, thanks for your answer. The problem is that I need to repeat this exercise and the columns can change location, I can have more then 3 columns (eg Monday Tuesday Wednesday Friday Colors)

For this reason I cannot set up a fixed range cells. Can I use the header of the column in order to write the if else function?

Any string of code would be very welcome.

Comment: Yeah you can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16013717/dynamic-column-selection-based-on-column-header-in-vba-excel